# How to get text after an element in xpath?

Tags: xpath, element, htmlunit, addressing

I have the following code and I am trying to address or read "HERE", using xpath.I am programming java and using page.getFirstByXPath method:

```
...
 <label item = "aaa">
  <input class = "bbb"/>
  <span class = "ccc">
  <span/>
  HERE
 <label/>
...
```

Cheers

Comment: Show what you've tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@item='aaa']")).getText();
```